# Are wasps attracted to a sting

Tags: wasps

A little backstory, I was trying to get something that was in a little wooded bit at the back of my garden and stepped on a swarm of wasps was stung 3 times and got out of there but I brought 8 wasps inside and was wondering if they know if you've been stung and are attracted to it and also out of curiosity what would happen to a wasp if it was stung by another wasp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tackling the second part of the question first: If a wasp is stung by another wasp, that's usually super bad for the wasp in question. Wasps are pretty good about not stinging one another, but occasionally wasps from other communities come in and cause a ruckus, or even predate on other communities of wasp specifically. If a wasp gets stung by one of these, it's about to die horribly, then get eaten.

On the other hand, if it's stung by 'friendly fire', it'll just die horribly. The venoms wasp stingers carry, while merely irritating and only occasionally fatal due to allergies on our scale, are generally pretty lethal to insects, arachnids, and other tiny critters; also, having a huge hole in your exoskeleton doesn't help.

As for the attraction question, the answer is a solid and absolute 'Eh, probably not.'.

Wasps, like a lot of insects, communicate on pheromones and dancing, but on the whole their 'deal' when not hunting is to *repel*, not kill. They don't care if what they sting gets killed or not; so long as it gets out of their zone of control. While they do issue alarm pheromones and other calls to action, these are not associated with stings in particular, which mostly deliver poison and sharp force trauma, not orders to the swarm.

You'll probably want to clean out the stings in *any case*, but it's unlikely that your new house guests want anything so much as just going home. Usher them out the door, and they'll be happy as clams.

Comment: I thought Wasps don't eat other insects, they do feed them to their larvae.

Comment: @RHA That seems like a petty distinction. Are wasp larvae not wasps?

Comment: Well, they have a different diet. Wasps eat sweet stuff (either excreted by the larvae or from your soft drink).

Comment: @RHA I think that varies by species. Wasps are freaks like that.

Comment: Well, all species of *Vespoidae* work like that. These are the colonybuilding, stinging creatures that most people call wasps. There are off course many solitary wasps, but these hardly ever sting people.

Comment: @RHA True enough. But if we're not rigorous in what constitutes a wasp, then why are we here?

Answer (score -1):

I was stung this afternoon. I drove home, washed the site with vinegar and was icing it, when out of nowhere a wasp came in through the open window and began to buzz around the part of my arm where I was icing. It landed, walked around for a few seconds, as if it was investigating. It was the oddest thing!

Comment: Hi. This is not an answer, but rather a comment about something that happened to you. Please delete this as an answer and move it to be a comment instead.